# Prove divergence of a series

Tags: analysis

I have to prove that $\frac{e^x}{x^k} \to \infty$  for $x \to \infty$ with $k \in \mathbb N$

My idea is to calculate for $R \gt 0$ an $x_r$ so that for every $ x\gt x_r$ the inequation $\frac{e^x}{x^k} \gt R$ applies.
So, I struggle with solving the equation $\frac{e^{x_r}}{x_{r}^k} = R$ for $x_r$

Comment: Where is the series that one must prove is divergent?

Answer (score 1):

As $\displaystyle e^x=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{x^r}{r!}$

For any finite $k\ge0,$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x}{x^k}\to\infty$$

Comment: I just wanted to know that can't we use l'hopital's rule in analysis? I've always studied it in calculus.

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi, Definitely, we can

Comment: ok. Thank you so much,

Answer (score 1):

From $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ you can follow that for $x>0$, we have $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}\geq \frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}.$$

Hence $\frac{e^x}{x^k} \geq \frac{x^{k+1}}{x^k (k+1)!} = \frac{x}{(k+1)!} \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Rather, note that, for every positive $x$, $\displaystyle \mathrm e^x=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\geqslant\frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$ hence $\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm e^x}{x^k}\geqslant\frac{x}{(k+1)!}\to+\infty$.